# SQLite get field slot from row 0 column 1 failed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to use an SQLite database to store some data for my app. I've got this in my DbHelper class (which extends SqLiteOpenHelper)

```
// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + jarsTable + "( "+colID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+colName+" varchar(100), " +
        colGoal+" real not null, "+colBal+" real not null, "+colCurr+" varchar(100));";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

And I've got this inside my DataSource class

```
private Jar cursorToJar(Cursor cursor) {
    Jar myJar = new Jar();
    myJar.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    myJar.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    myJar.setBalance(cursor.getDouble(2));
    myJar.setGoal(cursor.getDouble(3));
    myJar.setCurrency(cursor.getString(4));
    return myJar;
}
```

And I get the error I mentioned in the question title, which crashes the app, when it reaches the line myJar.setName above. I'm really a bit confused as to where I've gone wrong, I'm getting a string, and my table is storing a field at column 1, I think, so.. yeah. Thanks for the help, in advance

EDIT: Here's my population method:

```
public Jar createJar(String name, double goal, String currency) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DbHelper.colName, name);
    values.put(DbHelper.colGoal, goal);
    values.put(DbHelper.colCurr, currency);
    values.put(DbHelper.colBal, 0.0);
    long insertId = database.insert(DbHelper.jarsTable, null,
            values);
    Log.d("Insert ID:", ""+insertId);
    // To show how to query
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DbHelper.jarsTable,
            allColumns, DbHelper.colID + " = " + insertId, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursorToJar(cursor);
}
```

Comment: what error does the logcat give?

Comment: 02-07 20:05:11.240: E/AndroidRuntime(445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.nickavv.quickchange/com.nickavv.quickchange.JarList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col 1 failed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use the cursor's `getColumnIndex()` method to access columns. Like so:

```
myJar.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(colName)));
```

Not saying that's *absolutely* the issue -- since you haven't shown how the `Cursor` was populated -- but it's likely.

Comment: I changed them all to that, and now my error says Column -1 instead of Column 1, but otherwise seems the same

Comment: As I mentioned, you haven't shown how your `Cursor` got populated.

Comment: Ah, of course, sorry. I adapted all this code from an SQLite tutorial I found online, so apologies if there are glaring errors in it, haha

Comment: What is `allColumns` set to? Try removing it and setting that parameter to `null` and see if there's any difference.

Comment: It was set to private String[] allColumns = { DbHelper.colID };
Not sure why, again, just got it from the tutorial. However setting it to null seems to have fixed my issues. it doesn't crash, and the jar appears in the listview afterwards. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem is, that's the columns you're selecting from the database. It's a bit of a misnomer, too, since that's definitely not _all_ the columns :). You were basically _only_ pulling the colID column. That's why the other columns didn't show up. Setting it to `null` makes it pull all columns in the query. Glad you got it working.